# Multiple Correlation towards 2 target values

Tags: regression, correlation, classification

I am analyzing correlations between the driving speed of several drivers pairwise on the same route and correlations between them.

```
km  speed(driver1) speed(driver2)
0.1 56.7           61.4
0.2 58.2           60.9
0.3 57.1           59.2
....
```

.. and so on.

Now I include another parameter, "acceleration" for example.

```
km  speed(driver1) acc(driver1) speed(driver2) acc(driver2)
0.1 56.7           1.3             61.4        -0.1  
0.2 58.2           -0.3            60.9        -0.2
0.3 57.1           -0.4            59.2        0.7
....
```

Is it somehow possible to compute the correlation of both speed and acceleration together, so I get a measure how these two features combined are correlated between the two drivers?

I am doing the computations in R. However, I have also Rapidminer, Knime, Excel and Java installed.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Nonetheless, in order to provide assistance, information on the package used for the statistical analysis will be helpful.

Comment: I am doing the computations in R. However, I have also Rapidminer, Knime, Excel and Java installed.

Answer (score 0):

Using R Programming Language,

```
# generate random values for example
km <- round(runif(10, 0.1, 1.0), 1)
speedDriver1 <- round(runif(10, 50.1, 61.0), 1)
accDriver1 <- round(runif(10, -0.9, 0.9), 1)
speedDriver2 <- round(runif(10, 59.1, 70.0), 1)
accDriver2 <- round(runif(10, -0.9, 0.9), 1)

# combine into data frame
df <- data.frame(km, speedDriver2, accDriver1, speedDriver2, accDriver2)

# compute the correlation of speed and acceleration b/w the drivers
corTbl <- cor(df)

# print results
print(corTbl)
```

Correlation Matrix

```
                      km speedDriver2 accDriver1 speedDriver2.1 accDriver2
km             1.0000000    0.4370335  0.2992118      0.4370335  0.3146787
speedDriver2   0.4370335    1.0000000 -0.4782100      1.0000000  0.3287379
accDriver1     0.2992118   -0.4782100  1.0000000     -0.4782100 -0.5193500
speedDriver2.1 0.4370335    1.0000000 -0.4782100      1.0000000  0.3287379
accDriver2     0.3146787    0.3287379 -0.5193500      0.3287379  1.0000000
```